# Align image next to text

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

The problem is to align an image right to a variable length of text at the top. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}%
    \qquad%
    \parbox{0.1\textwidth}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image next to text]

I need the image to be in one line with the first sentence. I know I can individually raise the box. However, I'm searching for a general approach because I have quite a few of these cases in my document.

Comment: `\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}%` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only does the lipsum `\parbox` need to be top anchored, as Harish pointed out, but the rule box needs to be pushed downward.  One could use a `\raisebox` with an explicit negative value of pushdown, but that will vary with the height of what is being pushed down.  Here, instead, I set the top of the item (regardless of vertical size) to a position corresponding with the top of the `\strut`, meaning that the top of the rule box will split the gap between the two paragraphs shown in my MWE.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}%
    \qquad%
    \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\parbox{0.1\textwidth}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]